# Python Typecasting from a float String to Int not working in a for loop while creating a list

Tags: python, floating-point, boolean, try-except, typecasting-operator

the function
`def create_list()` takes in the number of elements required in a list. the user then inserts the elements to the list. the Goal was to cast strings of integers and floats to an integer then store the to the list. inputs that cant be converted are stored as strings., eg names the values from user and insert them into a list. The issue is that a float is still saved as a String

```
# create a list with a dynamic size
def create_list(num):
    num = int(num)
    my_list = []
    for i in range(num):
        inpt = input(f"enter element {i+1}:")
        try:
            if int(float(inpt)):
                my_list.append(int(inpt))
        except:
            my_list.append(inpt)

    print(f"Your List => : {my_list}")


create_list("5")


# print(type(5.751))
# print(int(5.751))
print(bool(int(5.751)))  #> For reference this returns True
```

here's my output: however the bool for `int(5.751)` returns `True`

```
enter element 1:23
enter element 2:jerry
enter element 3:46
enter element 4:griffin
enter element 5:67.65
Your List => : [23, 'jerry', 46, 'griffin', '67.65']
True
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. When the input is `67.65` (hint: as a string), what do you expect `my_list.append(int(inpt))` to do? (Hint: did you convert to `float` on this line? Did `if int(float(inpt)):` *change* `inpt`?)

Comment: thanks @Karl Knechtel.  yea, was a silly omission mistake for float conversion. on the line.  i guess in the idea of the condition evaluating to `True` made me oversee the essence of converting the floats

Answer (score 0):

Because you are using a try except block, it will catch all errors. When you try to append to the list, you don't call `float` first so `int` throws an exception when it detects the decimal point. Instead you should first convert it to a float and then int. For example:

```
def create_list(num):
    num = int(num)
    my_list = []
    for i in range(num):
        inpt = input(f"enter element {i+1}:")
        try:
            if int(float(inpt)):
                my_list.append(int(float(inpt)))
        except:
            my_list.append(inpt)

    print(f"Your List => : {my_list}")
```

Comment: oo yeah., hadn't thought of that. totally makes sense and works now. thanks @Advay168